# To select image from galary from Application sometimes it returns bitmap - nulll in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

In Application i open gallery and select image i have to show that image in dialog box..
bu sometimes it returen bitmap value =null.. and somtimes it has bitmap value does not show dialog box.. it throughs exceptioni.e

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 10:11:52.310: WARN/System.err(1395):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:432)
04-16 10:11:52.310: WARN/System.err(1395):     at myclassname.onActivityResult
```

for iopen gallery i used below code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setType("image/*");
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

Foe getting data from gallery i used this code

```
@Override 
              public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
              {
                   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                  if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                  { 
                      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                       try {

 Bitmap bitmap =   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                  }
                 }
```

Plz help ..

Comment: see images name .all are in small letter like file ?
and print your whole Logcat

Answer (score 0):

In you `onActivityResult` change the code to receive the image to this code,

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE) {

        Uri contentUri = data.getData();
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String tmppath = cursor.getString(column_index); // get path of image
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmppath); // decode path into bitmap
        iv.setImageBitmap(mBitmap); // set image to imageview
    }
```

Comment: I a have applied this also some image it returns tmppath =null;

Comment: what are you saying..really?..Are you working on Android 2.2?

Comment: I am working on Android 3.1 on Samsung Tablet i means that when i select image from gallery for some images it returns contentUri value =null